# Sub-Menu not staying open when mouse hovers over Menu item

Tags: jquery, html, submenu

I have a web page where there are navigation links. On hovering of certain navigation links, I want a separate menu to open up. I have managed to complete that. My problem is, when I hover over the particular navigation link, the sub-menu shows but when I try to click on a ink in the sub-menu, it disappears.

Here's my code  .ascx :

```
<div class="navigation">
    <h4 id="home"><a href="../Home.aspx">Home</a></h4>
    <h4 id="gallery"><a href="#">Gallery</a></h4>
        <div class="galList">
            <h4 id="newGal"><a href="#">New</a></h4>
                <div class="galNewList">
                    <h4><a href="#">Profile pictures</a></h4>
                    <h4><a href="#">Backgrounds</a></h4>
                </div>
            <h4 id="refundTick"><a href="#">Delete</a></h4>
        </div>
    <h4 id="about"><a href="#">About</a></h4>
</div>
```

.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.galList').hide();
    $('.galNewList').hide();

    $('#gallery').click(function () {
        if ($('.galList').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.galList').slideDown(500);
        }

        else {
            $('.galList').slideUp(500);
        }
    });

    $('#newGal').hover(function () {
        if ($('.galNewList').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.galNewList').show();
        }

        else {
            $('.galNewList').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Pete But if I was to use headings, how should I change my jQuery code? Help me please.

Comment: Have added an answer for your current html too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your html to be the following and it should make your js work as well as being more semantically correct:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.galList').hide();
  $('.galNewList').hide();

  $('#gallery').click(function() {
    if ($('.galList').is(':hidden')) {
      $('.galList').slideDown(500);
    } else {
      $('.galList').slideUp(500);
    }
  });

  $('#newGal').hover(function() {
    if ($('.galNewList').is(':hidden')) {
      $('.galNewList').show();
    } else {
      $('.galNewList').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.navigation,
.navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.navigation > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.navigation > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigation">
  <li id="home"><a href="../Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
  <li id="gallery">
    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    <ul class="galList">
      <li id="newGal">
        <a href="#">New</a>
        <ul class="galNewList">
          <li><a href="#">Profile pictures</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Backgrounds</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="refundTick"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem with your current html is that when you hover the "child items", they are not actually children of the hovered element so you are no longer hovering and the children will hide themselves again.

If you are desperate to keep your html structure, then you will need to change the selector for your hover:

```
$('#newGal,.galNewList').hover(function ....
```

And remove any margin between `newGal` and `galList` - if you need spacing, change it for padding:

```
h4 { margin:0; padding:5px 0; }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/o425mrwt/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That jQuery part actually worked even without me having to change all the menu items to `ul` tags. Thanks a million! Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome!  I was actually looking at your hover function and wasn't sure how it did the non hover bit so I changed it in this: http://jsfiddle.net/o425mrwt/2/ - if you look at the hover it has 2 functions - the first is when you enter and then the second is when you leave - it's just jquery's proper handling of the hover in and out